# Modify single column alignment in nattable

Tags: configuration, nattable

I am kind of a Newbie in nattable, I want change the alignment of first header column in nattable to the left and the rest remain on the right, I know that alignment is generally defined like this:

```
this.cHeaderHAlign = HorizontalAlignmentEnum.RIGHT;
```

Is it possible and How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet it looks like you are referring to theme configurations. But without going into details how this can be done using themes you need to understand how the basics are working.

In general you need to add a custom label to the first column in the column header and then apply a style object with the needed alignment for that label.

Have a look at the [NatTable - Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_configuration) to get an idea how this can be achieved.

Comment: I do something like this :   configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, firstheaderColumnLeftStyle,DisplayMode.NORMAL, RowsLabels.ALL_ROW_IN FIRST_COLUMN);

Comment: However headers alignment doesnot change, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: How did you add the label to the label stack of the column header cells? Typically the issue is that users add the labels only on the body layer stack and not the column header.

Comment: I have defined labels as static , calculate them in label acuumulator and use them in configuration , have i understood correctly?

Comment: yes, and where did you register the label accumulator to?

Comment: In BodyDataLayerConfiguration :  defined it as a style  :  Style firstheaderColumnLeftStyle = new Style();
   firstheaderColumnLeftStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT, HorizontalAlignmentEnum.LEFT);

Comment: Coming back to my initial statement, you are registering the label to the body and expect it to appear in the column header. That doesn't work! You need to add the label accumulator also to the column header configuration!

Comment: Ok, got it , thanks, could u look at my other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585691/2-image-in-root-of-tree-in-nattable

Comment: If you got it and it works, please accept the answer!