# 2 Image in root of tree in nattable

Tags: image, tree, nattable

I have inserted one image in the tree body in one of my columns with

```
 new TreeImagePainter(true, GUIHelper.getImage("right"), GUIHelper.getImage("right_down"), image);
```

in class `TreeConfiguration`, but I need to add one more image beside root rows.

Moreover I need to dynamicly obtain this image from some other class, where data is already read . As it turns out i can't because either this class is null or it is called later than it should. Could you guild me how to do that.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

The painting of the tree structure with node icons etc. is done by the `IndentedTreeImagePainter`. The `TreeImagePainter` is used as a decorator to the base painter for the content (typically text). If you need an additional icon you need to wrap the `IndentedTreeImagePainter` with another `CellPainterDecorator`.
Or in case the additional icon should be on the right of the tree icon, maybe the base painter can already be a `CellPainterDecorator` that combines both, an `ImagePainter` and a `TextPainter`.

If you only want to show that icon on root nodes, you will need some more customization, probably with a custom painter.

Sorry, I don't really understand your requirement.

Comment: Dirk could u take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038057/dynamic-background-in-nattable