# Dynamic background in nattable

Tags: nattable

I am reading some data from a javascript file and obtain the background color from it, it seems very simple but I cant find the proper function to dynamicly changed the background color base on these values. I have already tried changing configurations but it doesnot work, beacause the group of configlabels is not available for this colors.

BR,

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: I have a certain coloring on my columns and rows I wanna change the color of each cell based on its value, this rule is written in javascript, I read the rule andd extract the color but this is done in BodyDataLayerConfiguration and MyRowHeightTextPainter , I can change the text color but not its background.

Comment: Now I need to change the background color in some sort of backgroundpainter and I dont know how, is it clear?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware of the basic styling concepts in NatTable and therefore no, it is not clear to me what you are doing. In NatTable you register painters and styles that are interpreted by the painters. So I don't know what your painter is doing. And configuring the painters via styles is done via config labels. If you need something dynamic that reads and interpretes styles on the fly instead of using the NatTable mechanisms, implement your own painter and render the way you want.